# Access cookie values set by node server in the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, npm, setcookie

Currently am using node package coockie to set cookies from the backend like below

```
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('token', token, {
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
        }));
```

so I can access the token from the front end side like below

```
var ca = document.cookie.split(';').map(function (x) {
         return x.trim().split('=');
         }).reduce(function (a, b) {
              a[b[0]] = b[1];
              return a;
         }, {})["token"];
```

But when I set another one from the back end the second one will not set on the as a cookie.So as a solution for this I used

```
 res.cookie('refreshtoken', refreshToken, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 , httpOnly: true });
```

so from this I can set any no of cookie but the problem is this cookies cannot be accessed from the front end side.

So is there away to set more than one cookie from the backend and access all of them from the front end

Comment: Don't use `httpOnly: true`?

Comment: Nope tried that way @Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
httpOnly: true
```

This tells the browser that it should make the cookie available only to HTTP (i.e. not to client side JavaScript).

To read it with client side JS, simply don't do that.

Set the value to **false** instead.

Comment: What do u mean by simply don't access.Am simply saving the tokens to cookies.So I don't have to worry about sending them back to the server all time when am calling for server side resource.